# Switching elements between lists

Tags: c#

Hello I've been working on trying to switch elements from 2 list of integers by their index's.
My first list and second list has the following values.

```
list1 = {8, 2, 5, 1, 1}
list2 = {3, 4, 1, 7, 4}
```

I'm trying to switch the first 3 elements in both list and get the output like this.

```
list1 = {3, 4, 1, 1, 1}
list2 = {8, 2, 5, 7, 4}
```

Here's my code so far:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
            List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
            list1.Add(8);
            list1.Add(2);
            list1.Add(5);
            list1.Add(1);
            list1.Add(1);
            list2.Add(3);
            list2.Add(4);
            list2.Add(1);
            list2.Add(7);
            list2.Add(4);

            int index = 3;
            var firstPairItems = list1.Take(index);
            var secondPairItems = list2.Take(index);
            list1.InsertRange(indexPairs,secondPairItems);
            list2.InsertRange(indexPairs, firstPairItems);
```

I think I'm on the right track but instead of replacing it at the first 3 index it sort of adds the values at the index. Output right now of list1-

```
list1 = {8, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1 }
```

Any suggestions on another reliable way to solve it.

Comment: just a suggestion: use `List<int> list1 = new List<int>() {8, 2, 5, 1, 1};` and `List<int> list2 = new List<int>() {3, 4, 1, 7, 4};` to initialize your lists

Comment: You misunderstood the use of `Take`. Saying `.Take(3)` gives you a wrapper that will yield the **top-3** elements of the list when you enumerate (`foreach`) through it. It does not modify (remove from) the underlying list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists allow you to directly manipulate their elements by index, so you can just swap the elements like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var tmp = list1[i];
    list1[i] = list2[i];
    list2[i] = tmp;
}
```

If you needed a solution that would work for any `IEnumerable<T>`, not just lists, then you can use a little bit of Linq, like this:

```
var newList1 = list2.Take(3).Concat(list1.Skip(3));
var newList2 = list1.Take(3).Concat(list2.Skip(3));
```

Comment: oh ok thanks what if I had 4 lists and just wanted to switch list elements from list1 and list2 then switch between list3 and list4. It would still be the same right?

Comment: @CalvinJones Yes, same idea. If you wanted to do a sort of rotation, i.e. list1 --> list2 --> list3 --> list4, it would be `var tmp = list1[i]; list1[i] = list2[i]; list2[i] = list4[i]; list4[i] = tmp;` But at that point you may want make a list of lists to simplify things even more. I think you understand the logic though.

Comment: @p.s.w.g +1 for Linq solution. It's overkill though.

Comment: yeah ive been doing it with a list of list but the number arent going in to right place

Comment: @Leri It's not overkill if you only had `IEnumerable`'s to work with, but yes, for lists like this, a simple `for`-loop is a lot better. (admittedly the Linq code requires double iteration over the first 3 elements of each list, and that could be improved slightly by wrapping it up in another method which has some more complicated logic, but *that* seems like overkill)

Comment: @CalvinJones Care to explain? I've tested this code, and it seems to produce exactly what you wanted.

Comment: never mind thanks so much god bless you and everyone that helped me out

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to just exchange elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int tmp = list1[i];
    list1[i] = list2[i];;
    list2[i] = tmp;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ynQmHn)

However, there's one more solution which does not need temporary variable. But, IMHO, it's too much magic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    list2[i] = list1[i] ^ list2[i];
    list1[i] = list2[i] ^ list1[i];
    list2[i] = list1[i] ^ list2[i];
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/VnCT9Y)

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    list2[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
    list1[i] = list2[i] - list1[i];
    list2[i] = list2[i] - list1[i];
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/bxKRTL)

**Note:** I have hardcoded `3` in answer just to keep it short. In real world you want to avoid this [*magic number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) and make it a constant or variable depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

very simple

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int newVariable= list1[i];
    list1[i] = list2[i];;
    list2[i] = newVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Linq** for this:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 8, 2, 5, 1, 1 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 1, 7, 4 };

list2.InsertRange(0, list1.Take(3));
list1.RemoveRange(0, 3);

// 3 items have been inserted already, so we should skip them
list1.InsertRange(0, list2.Skip(3).Take(3));
list2.RemoveRange(3, 3);
```